# Svg path is not animating in React Spring animating library

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-spring

I have trying to implement the same example as shown in [react-spring](http://react-spring.surge.sh/spring) docs of svg path animation but It renders immediately:
Here is my code:

```
<Spring from={{ x: 0 }} to={{ x: 100 }}>
  {props => (
    <svg strokeDashoffset={props.x}>
      <path d="M7 2v11h3v9l7-12h-4l4-8z" />
    </svg>
  )}
</Spring>
```

Here is my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/9llxp0zx8o

Svg path is not animated as expected like in example 2 here: http://react-spring.surge.sh/spring

I think I'm missing something here. I'll be glad if someone could find the issue and put me in the direction.

Answer (score 1):

To animate it like in the example, you need to also set the strokeDasharray value to the length of the SVG path. Here's an example for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scrolldrawing.asp

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useSpring } from '@react-spring/core'
import { animated } from '@react-spring/web'

export const CirclePath = () => {
  const circleRef = useRef()
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => setOffset(circleRef.current.getTotalLength()), [offset])
  const config = useSpring({
    from: { offset },
    to: { offset: 0 },
  })

  return (
    <svg>
      <animated.circle
        ref={circleRef}
        cx='50'
        cy='50'
        r='30'
        strokeDashoffset={config.offset}
        strokeDasharray={offset}
        stroke='black'
        strokeWidth='2'
        fill='none'
      ></animated.circle>
    </svg>
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```